# Udev rule refuses to trigger when harddrive is added

Tags: rsync, hard-disk, backup, udev, storage

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.

I'm trying to execute an action when a specific harddrive is connected using an udev rule identifying the drive using UUID. The script will eventually do a routine where it will mount the drive and run rsync. To rule out any errors in that process I'm now just trying out a test command.

The harddrive is connected via SATA Hotswap and has an UUID which is confirmed to be correct. I've followed numerous guides that seem to use this exact syntax, and still absolutely nothing happens however I try.

Here are the steps I've done:

- Created a file called 90-backup.rules in `/etc/udev/rules.d`. The content is:

`ACTION=="add", ENV{ID_FS_UUID}=="b527aadc-9dce-4ead-8937-e53ca2cfac84", RUN+="/bin/echo 1 >> /rule.test"`

- Tried
  `udevadm control --reload-rules && udevadm trigger`
- Tried `systemctl reload udev`
- Running `udevadm test /dev/sdX` i can see that it lists the rules file:

`Reading rules file: /etc/udev/rules.d/90-backup.rules`

- Using `udevadm info /dev/sdX` confirm that the ID_FS_UUID environmental variable is correct and can be read.
- Tried adding `KERNEL=='sd?'` before the `ACTION` argument.

Since the server is currently live in use, I haven't tried rebooting it yet. And it would be good to once and for all establish what is necessary to have udev reload the rules properly without reboot, for proper debugging.

Any help is appreciated.

All the best,
Andreas

Answer (score 0):

> `RUN+="/bin/echo 1 >> /rule.test`

Instead of trying to redirect output (which I don't think really works when done in a `udev` rule's `RUN` process), have the `RUN` process use a shell script to run whichever commands you need.

During debugging it would be useful to keep track of when the script worked, so create a shell script by saving the code below to `/usr/local/bin/myscript.sh` (obviously give it whatever name you want):

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
printf '%s\n' "Script run by udev $( date +%c )" > /tmp/rule-test
```

The above script will write the current time to a `rule-test` file in `/tmp` directory whenever the script is run. But you need to give the script execute permissions:

`sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/myscript.sh`

Now change your udev rule so the RUN part contains the full path to your script:

```
ACTION=="add", ENV{ID_FS_UUID}=="b527aadc-9dce-4ead-8937-e53ca2cfac84", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/myscript.sh"
```

Finally reload the `udev` rules:

```
sudo udevadm control --reload
```

Now connect your hard drive and see if the time gets written to `/tmp/rule-test`.

Once it works, you can set up `myscript.sh` to do different things you want (run `rsync` for example) and you won't have to continue making changes to udev rules - just change the shell script.

> what is necessary to have `udev` reload the rules properly without reboot

Use `sudo udevadm control --reload`.

Comment: What exactly makes `/rule-test` an invalid file name? It's a normal path for a normal file in the root directory. And udev has privileges to write there; the level of sandboxing that you describe isn't part of the standard configuration at all. (And if it *were* sandboxed to the extent of not even having a /tmp, it'd be extremely unlikely that it would still have full write access to /home...)

Comment: Actually now that I test it again, it does write to `/tmp` so I have no idea what the problem was last night. Not sure why I thought `/rule-test` was an invalid name, but I was kinda tired with I wrote that. Fixed now.